# Sumar valores repetidos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Tengo esta tabla. Requiero sumar todos los elementos repetidos de las `(18,19,20)`:

[image: captura de registros]

Algo así debería quedar:

[image: captura del resultado]

---

**Obtengo todas las órdenes:**

```
$ordenes_id = OrderWork::select('id')->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)->get();
```

**Recorro la matriz:**

```
foreach($ordenes_id as $k => $ord_id){
   $id = $ord_id->id;
   $plan = Plantilla::select('cat_format_id')->where('orden_trabajo_id', '=', $id)->get();
   
   foreach($plan as $in => $lin){
       $forma = $lin->cat_format_id;
       $bal = Plantilla::select('balance')->where('orden_trabajo_id', '=', $id)->where('cat_format_id', '=', $forma)->get();
       $unidad = $bal[0]->balance;
       echo "forma_id =" .$forma. " ,numero = " .$unidad. "<br/>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

encontre la solucion con el siguiente comando de MYSQL

```
$datas = DB::select('select  cat_format_id, cat_format_name, sum( balance) as total
from    orden_plantilla, orden_trabajo
where   orden_trabajo.company_id = ' . $company_id . '
and     orden_plantilla.orden_trabajo_id = orden_trabajo.id
group by cat_format_id, cat_format_name');
```

Esto medio la suma correcta de cada uno de los registros por cliente, espero que en futuras referencias les pueda ayudar

Saludos

Comment: Es un gran fallo de seguridad el hecho de estar concatenando de forma directa variables dentro de la consulta

Comment: Por favor consulta como recomienda el framework trabajar con el paso de valores dinámicos: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-a-select-query